# Cannot find referecnce to WLResourceRequest in Ionic 2 App

Tags: cordova, angular, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic2

I created a provider in Ionic 2 (**v 2.0.0-beta.32**) App powered by IBM MobileFirst Platform 8.0 (**mfpdev verion 8.0.0-2016070716**) Beta. Following is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
  data: any;

  constructor() {
    this.data = null;
  }

  load() {
    console.log('--> called employee service');
    if (this.data) {
      // already loaded data
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    let dataRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/messangerAdapter/getEmployeeRating",WLResourceRequest.GET);
      /*dataRequest.send().then((response) => {
        console.log('--> adapter response recieved', response.responseJSON.results);
        this.data = response.responseJSON.results;
        resolve(this.data);
      });*/
    });
  }
}
```

When I am compiling the code I am getting the following error:

```
TypeScript error: E:/Worklight Mobile App/MFP 8.0 Eclipse and WS/workspace/MobileApp/TestProject/app/providers/employee-service/employee-service.ts(30,94): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WLResourceRequest'.
```

I have added the mfp plugin to the ionic project. Is there something else i have to do in order to make that work?

Comment: Can you try using the latest version of MobileFirst Platform 8.0 and not Beta. If the issue still exists please provide a sample reproducing the issue to verify.

Comment: @S.A.NortonStanley..updated to V8.0.0-2016070716 still giving the same error.

Comment: Can you provide your app?

Comment: @IdanAdar I uploded the project to following location : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34608293/Test.zip

You need to install the npm modules in order to make that work.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Tried your sample and i see no error on my machine. 

 Steps i followed:
   - Downloaded your sample
   - Did an npm install (my npm version 3.9.5)
   - Performed a cordova prepare
   - Performed a cordova run andriod

Result: The app launched without any error. 
   
Screenshot and logs can be found here: 
    https://ibm.box.com/s/oz1t7g0hup2fwukpejbb82di0k54ehss 
    https://ibm.box.com/s/hms8q8fn2tr1g5vxr1y2cb8bw5gtprn0
    https://ibm.box.com/s/aynk6lru8n752ulxn95wolfrsc9td16f

Comment: "8.0.0-2016070716" is NOT "beta". It is the GA version. What is your MobileFirst Server? the beta devkit or a Bluemix service?

Comment: @IdanAdar I an using beta devkit version. You want me to upgrade it?

Comment: Yes, you must. GA SDK is not compatible with Beta devkit. Until the GA devkit is available, use the Mobile Foundation Bluemix service as your server.

Comment: Even though no directly related to your issue, you have to upgrade your server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try adding this as first line of your file? (Before `import`)

```
/// <reference path="../../../plugins/cordova-plugin-mfp/typings/worklight.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Strange but the app worked out of the box for me. Did not have to change any reference.