# How to use IBM MFP 8.0 functions(WL, WLResourceRequest) in ionic 2 development

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I am a fresher in IBM MobileFirst 8.0. How to use IBM MFP functions(WL, WLResourceRequest) in ionic 2 projects?

I have created an Ionic Project and added MFP plugin and I added the below lines into Home Component TS file.

```
WL.Client.setSharedToken({key: "name", value: "Karhik"});
    let str: String = WL.Client.getSharedToken({key: "name"});
    console.log(str);
```

But I am getting the below error. How to solve the issue. Or given any reference documents for Ionic 2 + IBM MFP 8.0

[image]

And I tried to like this below. But same error is returned,

```
Home.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

declare var wlCommonInit: () => {

};

declare var WL;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [ Device ]
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private device: Device) {
    console.log("device platform " + device.platform);

    WL.Client.setSharedToken({key: "name", value: "Karhik"});
    let str: String = WL.Client.getSharedToken({key: "name"});
    console.log(str);
  }

  wlCommonInit() {
    console.log("wlCommonInit TRIGGERED");

  }

}
```

But it not working. I need to know how to use **IBM MFP 8.0** in **IONIC 2**

After adding the code into Main.ts Below error is returned in console.

[image]

Comment: This error happens if you invoke WL objects before MFP plugin initialization is complete.
You should wait until MFP bootstrapping is complete , to add any code that initializes MFP objects - "WL" and others.

Comment: Hi, Any event will trigger after MFP bootstrapping is completed? or Any other sample you have please post for my reference.

Comment: I would suggest you put your code in wlcommoninit()

Comment: Hi, I am using Ionic 2, I don't know where to add wlcommoninit() method. There doesn't have any main.js. There have main.ts. If i add the wlcommoninit() function in HomeComponent. I getting 'wlcommoninit() is declared but not used'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find referecnce to WLResourceRequest in Ionic 2 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356571/cannot-find-referecnce-to-wlresourcerequest-in-ionic-2-app)

Answer (score 2):

WL has to be loaded before other javascript files for WL functions to be available in these files. The initialization of WL happens in `wlcommoninit()` (it's usage can be found [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/19/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic-based-apps/)). The recommended approach is to ensure that the other js files are loaded in this function.

An alternative to overcome this issue is to ensure that the below 3 scripts are included before the other js scripts in the html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/platform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, Keerthi. I am using Ionic 2, There have only main.ts

Comment: In your ts file, move the WL.Client.setSharedKey() to within wlCommonInit.
Another document you can use:
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/11/best-practices-for-building-angularjs-apps-with-mobilefirst-foundation-8.0/

Comment: wlCommonInit() function is not triggered.  @Vivin K

Comment: I added the wlcommoninit in this file temporary. But it not triggered. If I paste the code into wlcommonint. This line not run.

Comment: Can you try the solution @Keerthi has suggested? If not provide your sample that recreates the issue

Comment: Ya @VivinK I tried. But it not working. I don't have any platform.js file.

Comment: Please share if you have any sample with MFP and Ionic 2

Comment: platform.js is an illustration. Put the file where you have your wlCommonInit()

Comment: Please understand. I don't know where to add the wlCommonInit() in Ionic 2 project. In ionic v1, I tried and its working fine. please help me how to use MFP in ionic 2.

Comment: Hi Keerthi, I tried. I am getting,      
'wlCommonInit' is declared but never used.

 L7:  declare var WL;
 L8:  function wlCommonInit() {
 L9:      console.log("wlCommonInit TRIGGERED");

I attached the screenshot in my question.

Comment: wlCommonInit is not triggered

Comment: wlCommonInit  is not triggered.I wrote in app.component.ts.please share solution

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line before the import statements instead of declaring `WL` and `wlCommonInit`.

`/// <reference path="../../../plugins/cordova-plugin-mfp/typings/worklight.d.ts" />`

This should resolve the issue which you are facing.